# Consider defining a bean of type 'tacos.repository.IngredientRepository' in your configuration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm learning the spring data jpa thorough spring in Action.when i learned to chapter3, thtare application start error.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of method dataLoader in tacos.TacoCloudApplication required a bean of type 'tacos.repository.IngredientRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'tacos.repository.IngredientRepository' in your configuration.
```

the code structure like https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIvMG.png

the TacoCloudApplication code is:

```java
package tacos;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Comment;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

import tacos.bean.Ingredient;
import tacos.bean.Ingredient.Type;
import tacos.repository.IngredientRepository;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"bean", "controller", "converter","repository"})
public class TacoCloudApplication {
    
    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner dataLoader(IngredientRepository repo) {
        
        return args -> {
            repo.deleteAll();
            repo.save(new Ingredient("FLTO", "Flour Tortilla", Type.WRAP));
             repo.save(new Ingredient("COTO", "Corn Tortilla", Type.WRAP));
             repo.save(new Ingredient("GRBF", "Ground Beef", Type.PROTEIN));
             repo.save(new Ingredient("CARN", "Carnitas", Type.PROTEIN));
             repo.save(new Ingredient("TMTO", "Diced Tomatoes", Type.VEGGIES));
             repo.save(new Ingredient("LETC", "Lettuce", Type.VEGGIES));
             repo.save(new Ingredient("CHED", "Cheddar", Type.CHEESE));
             repo.save(new Ingredient("JACK", "Monterrey Jack", Type.CHEESE));
             repo.save(new Ingredient("SLSA", "Salsa", Type.SAUCE));
             repo.save(new Ingredient("SRCR", "Sour Cream", Type.SAUCE));
            
            
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TacoCloudApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

the IngredientRepository code is :

```java
package tacos.repository;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import tacos.bean.Ingredient;
public interface IngredientRepository extends CrudRepository<Ingredient, String>{

}
```

DesignTacoController code is:

```java
package tacos.controller;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.SessionAttributes;

import jakarta.validation.Valid;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import tacos.bean.Ingredient;
import tacos.bean.Ingredient.Type;
import tacos.bean.Taco;
import tacos.bean.TacoOrder;
import tacos.repository.IngredientRepository;

@Controller
@Slf4j
@RequestMapping("/")
@SessionAttributes("tacoOrder")
public class DesignTacoController {
    @Autowired(required = true)
    private  IngredientRepository ingredientRepo;
    
    
//  @Autowired
//  public DesignTacoController(IngredientRepository ingredientRepo) {
//      this.ingredientRepo = ingredientRepo;
//  }
    
    
    @ModelAttribute
    public void addIngredientsToModel(Model model) {
//      List<Ingredient> ibgredients = Arrays.asList(
//              new Ingredient("FLTO", "Flour Tortilla", Type.WRAP),
//               new Ingredient("COTO", "Corn Tortilla", Type.WRAP),
//               new Ingredient("GRBF", "Ground Beef", Type.PROTEIN),
//               new Ingredient("CARN", "Carnitas", Type.PROTEIN),
//               new Ingredient("TMTO", "Diced Tomatoes", Type.VEGGIES),
//               new Ingredient("LETC", "Lettuce", Type.VEGGIES),
//               new Ingredient("CHED", "Cheddar", Type.CHEESE),
//               new Ingredient("JACK", "Monterrey Jack", Type.CHEESE),
//               new Ingredient("SLSA", "Salsa", Type.SAUCE),
//               new Ingredient("SRCR", "Sour Cream", Type.SAUCE)
//      );
        
        List<Ingredient> ingredients = new ArrayList<>();
        ingredientRepo.findAll().forEach(ig -> ingredients.add(ig));
        
        for (Type type : Type.values()) {
            model.addAttribute(type.toString().toLowerCase(), filterByType(type, ingredients));
        }
    }
    
    @ModelAttribute(name = "tacoOrder")
    public TacoOrder order() {
        return new TacoOrder();
    }
    
    @ModelAttribute(name = "taco")
    public Taco taco() {
        return new Taco();
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/design")
    public String showDesignForm() {
        return "design";
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/design")
    public String processTaco(@Valid Taco taco, Errors errors, @ModelAttribute TacoOrder tacoOrder) {
        
        if(errors.hasErrors()) {
            errors.getAllErrors().stream().forEach(s -> log.info("{}", s));
            return "design";
        }
        
        tacoOrder.addTaco(taco);
        log.info("Processing taco: {}", taco);
        
        return "redirect:/orders/current";
        
    }
    
    private List<Ingredient> filterByType(Type type, List<Ingredient> list) {
        return list.stream()
                .filter(x-> x.getType().equals(type))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

}
```

my pom.xml is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0-M2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>sia</groupId>
    <artifactId>taco-cloud</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>taco-cloud</name>
    <description>Taco Cloud Example</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

the problem is the method dataLoader's param repo can't Autowired, i tried a lof way to fix this problem,but i failed, someone can help me what should I do?

Comment: Your `scanBasePackages` looks wrong to me as they're all nested beneath `tacos`. Have you tried `tacos.bean`, `tacos.controller`, and so on? Alternatively, you could remove `scanBasePackages` entirely and just use `@SpringBootApplication` and its defaults instead.

Comment: i tried tacos.bean....and i also remove scanBasePackages entirely,but the problem still exisit

Comment: Then please share a [minimal, reproducible example](/help/mcve)

Comment: i already added the reletive code, please help. I wonder why DesignTacoController. dataLoader Methond paramter can not Autowired.  but DesignTacoController can autowired

Comment: Remove the `scanBasePackages`, remove the `org.eclipse.persistence` dependency and the exclude for `hibernate-core`. Spring Boot provides auto configuration for Hibernate only, if you want to use Eclipse JPA you will need to manually configure JPA. Additionally the version included isn't even compatible with the Spring Boot version in use as it uses JPA 2 whilst you need JPA3 with Spring Boot 3.